# iOS: FMDB questions adding a lot of data to an array

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, nsmutablearray, fmdb

I am getting a lot of data from the database. This is an example on what I am doing.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myTable"];
while ([s next]) {
     NSString *idNumber = [result stringForColumn:@"id"];
     [array addObject:idNumber];
}
```

However, there is one issue that is making me nervous. What if I need to grab a lot of data from the database? Will this cause any memory issue or major slow downs? If so, what will be the best way to make sure this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: You answered your question yourself. Just don't grab hall data. Use filters `WHERE`.

Comment: What if I need to get a lot of data? It is a rare occurrence for this, but sometimes I need to grab all the data and make sure my Array is up to date with the database.

Comment: If so, use background thread, to be sure that you won't eat resources from main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use query with filters `WHERE`
2. Use background thread
3. You're using only `id` field, so there's no need to grab all other fields: use `SELECT id FROM myTable` instead

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, I have one last question. Is loading that much ids into an array going to cause any memory issues. I haven't notice any, but just want to be sure.

Comment: It should be pretty safe for any regular uses.